# Mysql - "subquery returns more than 1 row" error

Tags: mysql

I have two tables :

**ingredients**

```
|   id   |       iName      |
-----------------------------
|   101  |     Curcumin     |
|   102  |     Riboflavin   |
|   103  |     Protease     |
|   104  |    Tartrazine    |
|   105  |      Amylase     |
```

**foodproduct_ingredient**

```
|  foodproduct_id  |  ingredient_id   |
---------------------------------------
|         1        |        101       |
|         1        |        102       |
|         1        |        104       |
```

And I just want to get list iName for every single foodproduct. 
For example, when I want to get iName in **foodproducts.id = 1** must be

```
|        iName       |
----------------------
|      Curcumin      |
|      Riboflavin    |
|      Tartrazine    |
```

I have tried to insert query :

```
SELECT ingredients.iName FROM ingredients INNER JOIN foodproduct_ingredient 
        ON ingredients.id = foodproduct_ingredient.foodProduct_id 
        WHERE ingredients.id = 
        (SELECT foodproduct_ingredient.ingredient_id FROM foodproduct_ingredient INNER JOIN foodproducts 
        ON foodproducts.id = foodproduct_ingredient.foodProduct_id 
        WHERE foodproducts.id = 1)
```

but it returns *subquery returns more than 1 row*

Can somebody help me? Thanks :)

*Note : there is table **foodproducts** just for join to get id of foodproducts

Comment: Use `IN` instead of `= `...or you can add `LIMIT 1` to your subquery

Comment: You've overcomplicated your query significantly, and are likely using incorrect conditions, such as `ingredients.id = foodproduct_ingredient.foodProduct_id`. Also, unless you want some other information from `foodproducts` you don't actually need to reference that table; you've already stated/implied you have the id from that table. _This should be a simple two-table join with a single-condition where clause; ask yourself the info you want, where it comes from, and what info you have to get to it._

Comment: @Uueerdo yes I want to reference id from table foodproducts too, so I join that table

Comment: `WHERE foodproducts.id = 1` suggests you already know the id value you want information for; that value is (or should be) directly referenced in your linking (`foodproduct_ingredient`) table as `foodproduct_id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `IN` clause

```
SELECT ingredients.iName FROM ingredients INNER JOIN foodproduct_ingredient 
    ON ingredients.id = foodproduct_ingredient.foodProduct_id 
    WHERE ingredients.id In 
    (SELECT foodproduct_ingredient.ingredient_id FROM foodproduct_ingredient INNER JOIN foodproducts 
    ON foodproducts.id = foodproduct_ingredient.foodProduct_id 
    WHERE foodproducts.id = 1)
```

By the way you wont even need subquery i guess. Try to use below query

```
select i.iName from ingredients i
join foodproduct_ingredient fi
on fi.ingredient_id = i.id
where fi.foodproduct_id = 1
```

Comment: @AdnanFajri can you also try other query i wrote.

Comment: in your query, doesnt reference id from foodproducts table

Comment: @AdnanFajri Edited query. please check and accept answer if possible